# Render partials from uncompiled templates with Dust.js

Tags: dust.js

Can I do something like:

```
<script type="text/template" id="header">
  yo
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="body">
  {>"header"/}
  whats up
</script>

<script>
  // I'm just citing a backbone example...
  this.z = 'x';
  dust.loadSource(dust.compile($('#body').html(),this.z));
  dust.render(this.z, null, function(err, out) {
    _self.$el.html(out);
  });
</script>

<script src="dust-full-1.2.0.js"></script>
```

Is it possible to render partials in a similiar way without precompiling partial?

Is there a recursive way to precompile dependant partials when using `dust.render()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Dan, you need to compile all the templates. 
Because dust will look for the templates in the dust's cache. So if you don't compile the partial and load it in the cache (with loadsource) it will not find it.
I have being using backbone with dust, and I using a nodejs script that compiles automatically all my templates when I save them. you can see it here: https://github.com/dmix/dusterjs

Comment: Yea I've used your solution before it's very helpful. Bit of a shame there's no way to do this. I was thinking it would be useful to speed development before compiling everything out.